# How to check wether a cell contains a date in a specific format?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a sheet where a user inputs a date and then starts a macro to get information from that date. But the date must be in the format YYYY-MM-DD for the macro to work. This is my code:

```
If Sheets("DeliveryResults").Range("Q19").NumberFormat <> "yyyy-mm-dd" Then
    MsgBox ("Write the date in the format YYYY-MM-DD")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

It doesn't work. It gives the error message even if the date is in the correct format. Anyone knows why?

This is the code that uses the date entered in the cell:

```
Dim Today As Date
Dim Yesterday As Date
Today = Sheets("Resultat").Range("Q19").Value
Yesterday = Today - 1
Dim starthour As Date
starthour = Today & " 07:00:00"
```

The dates in the data that the macro reads from is formatted as "2020-02-26 19:27:30"

/Jens

Comment: If you work with true dates the formatting does not matter, it only matters if you are working with text strings that look like dates.  Show the code part that works with this date.

Comment: Dim Today As Date, 
Dim Yesterday As Date,
Today = Sheets("DeliveryResults").Range("Q19").Value, 
Yesterday = Today - 1

Comment: dim starthour as date, starthour = Today & " 07:00:00"

Comment: That's the code that creates the date.

Comment: The dates in the data that the macro reads from is formatted as "2020-02-26 19:24:30"

Comment: Rule of thumb, you don't want to concatenate string literals with dates, or do number math with them. Use the appropriate functions in the `VBA.DateTime` module instead.

Comment: `startHour = Today + TimeSerial(7,0,0)`

Comment: Well Today could be any date. Might change the name for the variable. In the first version you could only check todays date. I'm trying to change that now.

Comment: Yes if it's any date then please use a different variable name.

Comment: Ok so how do I check if the date in the cell has the correct format? Is numberformat the right way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Your message does not show enough information to define the problem.  Try something like:

```
Sub qwerty()
If Sheets("DeliveryResults").Range("Q19").NumberFormat <> "yyyy-mm-dd" Then
    MsgBox ("Q19 has NumberFormat" & Chr(10) & Sheets("DeliveryResults").Range("Q19").NumberFormat & Chr(10) & "use yyyy-mm-dd instead")
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code that doesn't work is the if statement. It should execute only if the date format is different that YYYY-MM-DD, but it executes regardless if the date format is correct or not.

Comment: @Jens  **That is my point.**  You need to see what the NumberFormat IS to determine why the code is not working.

Comment: I tried it and it says that the cell has the format m/d/yyyy. But that doesn't work either. I changed the line to  `If Sheets("DeliveryResults").Range("Q19").NumberFormat <> "m/d/yyyy" Then` but it gave the same result.

Comment: Wait it does work but now it accepts all numbers that looks like dates. 435-87-4 passes through. And 2020-02-26, 02-26-2020, and 26-02-2020 all works as well. Would be a problem with dates like 03-04, is it the third of may or the fourth of march?